# How to change side margins in Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-5

How to change the default side margins on .container in Bootstrap? Basically any content that is placed in Bootstrap system..

Comment: Please clarify what "margins" you mean. Do you mean the spacing inside the container or that the container is centered on the page? Do you have code to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`.

`.container` - sets a max-width at each responsive breakpoint.

`.container-fluid` - sets width: 100% at all breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override the styles set by BS in a stylesheet loaded after BS. In order to know exactly what you need to override, you can just inspect the container element in your browser.
So, the default BS style rule is as follows:

```css
.container, .container-fluid, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: var(--bs-gutter-x,.75rem);
    padding-left: var(--bs-gutter-x,.75rem);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

The snippet below demonstrates how to change the left and right margins:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .container,
  .container-fluid,
  .container-lg,
  .container-md,
  .container-sm,
  .container-xl,
  .container-xxl {
    margin-right: 5em;
    margin-left: 5em;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Grid</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```